# Div + JQuery Not Clearing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I'm using JQuery Masonry in my website and it works fine on the page except the cells aren't being cleared after the last one. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#pageMain').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.post'
  });
});
</script>

<div id="pageMain">
    <?php
    <div class=\"section halfSection post\">
        <div class=\"sectionInner\">
            <img class=\"photo190\" src=\"content/news/$article_photo\" alt=\"\" />
            <div class=\"cover190\"></div>
            <div class=\"shadow190\"></div>
            <div class=\"newsTitle\"><strong>$article_title</strong></div>
            <div class=\"newsArticle\">$article_article ...<br><a class=\"newsLink\" href=\"article.php?id=$article_id\">Full Story</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    { x 20 }

    ?>
    <div class="clearLeft"></div>
</div>

.post{
position: relative;
float: left;
}
.clearLeft{
clear: left;
}
```

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clear them, as masonry sets the height of their container to an absolute PX value based on the height of its contents. Items inside are positioned absolutely too, not with floats. So clear wouldn't have any effect.

Just place content you want under the grid after (outside of) `<div id="pageMain">` and you should be fine :)

If you find that they ARE definitely floating and need to be cleared, I would guess that masonry has not  been initialised. Check your JS console for errors. As this is good fallback behaviour anyway, you can apply `overflow: hidden` to the CSS of `#pageMain` to clear its contents.

Comment: I have to use clearLeft because section is given a float class too - What you're saying is that the code I have should work fine?

Comment: Thanks but I've sorted it now - It may be because #mainPage was floated left too so I put another div within #mainPage and everything works fine again

Comment: Ah. That may well have been your problem!

Comment: Yeah, I copied the code from a previous website that I had developed where .pageMain wasn't floated so I'm guessing that was the problem